# SAML Authentication request to Gluu server

Tags: saml, opensaml

How can pass username password as attributes in SAML Request as shown in the code below. I'm using lastpass-saml-sdk.jar to communicate with the GLUU IDP server.

```
SAMLInit.initialize();
String dir = Constants.METADATA_LOCATION;
if (dir == null)
    throw new SAMLException("Unable to locate SAML metadata");

IdPConfig idpConfig = new IdPConfig(new File(dir + "\\gluu-idp-metadata.xml"));
SPConfig spConfig = new SPConfig(new File(dir + "\\sp-meta.xml"));

SAMLClient client= new SAMLClient(spConfig, idpConfig);

// when a login link is clicked, create auth request and
// redirect to the IdP
String requestId = SAMLUtils.generateRequestId();
String authrequest = client.generateAuthnRequest(requestId);

String url = client.getIdPConfig().getLoginUrl() +
             "?SAMLRequest=" + URLEncoder.encode(authrequest, "UTF-8");

// redirect to url...

response.sendRedirect(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not pass username and passord directly to the Identity Provider. After you have redirected the user, the user himself will enter username and password at the IDP.

[Here is one of my blog posts](http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/05/saml-web-profile.html) describing the flow in SAML Web rowser profile.